# Having issues when trying to bounce off a wall with wall jump C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools

So this is my wall jump, it works fine, and I can even get the character to bounce back off the wall slightly when wall jumping off of the left wall using `SetHorizontalForce (10);`. So the problem I am running into is when I put `SetHorizontalForce (-10);` to bounce off the right wall it makes it so the character can no longer climb up the wall, instead he bounces back off the wall but doesn't gain any more height. Is this `SetHorizontalForce (-10);` somehow effecting the character's y axis? Or is something else entirely happening?

```
public void WallJump()
{   
    if (State.HasCollisions) {
        AddForce (new Vector2 (0, Parameters.JumpMagnitude));
        _jumpIn = Parameters.JumpFrequency;
    }
    if (State.IsColidingLeft) {
        SetHorizontalForce (10);
        _dashIn = Para.DashFrequency;
    }
    else if (State.IsColidingRight){
        SetHorizontalForce (-10);
        _dashIn = Para.DashFrequency;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I was asked to include my SetHorizontalForce, so here it is:**

```
private Vector2 _velocity;

    public void SetHorizontalForce(float x)
    {
    _velocity.x = x;
    }
```

**EDIT2: This is how my _velocity is handled.**

```
public void AddForce(Vector2 force)
{
    _velocity = force;
}
public void SetForce(Vector2 force)
{
    _velocity += force;
}
public void SetHorizontalForce(float x)
{
    _velocity.x = x;
}
public void SetVerticalForce(float y)
{
    _velocity.y = y;
}
```

Comment: Weird, I'm unable to find a SetHorizontalForce in the docs. Is that something you rolled yourself? If so then could you include it?

Comment: @Terrance Hey man, I've included my SetHorizontalForce, if anything else is needed feel free to ask. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It would also help if you showed me the rest of the class as well. Is there somewhere you are setting _velocity to the actual velocity of the game object? Also are you calling Wall Jump in FixedUpdate Or Update or some other method\co-routine?

Comment: @Terrance 
Added my _velocity

Comment: Oh so you aren't using the unity2d rigidbody physics then? Are you rolling your own physics?

Comment: Not that it isn't a valid choice or anything but, is there a reason you preferred rolling your own physic instead of using unity's baked in box2d implementation?

Comment: @Terrance Yeah, the 2d physics in unity seems to be really buggy when it comes to moving up and down slopes and a few other small things but at this point I'm looking further into using their physics anyway. Seems like at the very least there is a lot of people who know their way around it. Thanks a lot for the replies man, I appreciate it.

Comment: I cant say I've had problems with the unity physics.

Answer (score 0):

So you're wondering why it isn't going up any more if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

I'm not seeing you actually add a force in the vertical direction. If you want them to continue climbing upward, then you need to send them in a horizontal as well as a vertical direction in order for them to keep wall jumping in an upward direction, otherwise, they are only using the initial jump force, and once the apex is reached, they'll just start to fall down more and more.

If you need more of an explanation, let me know, but yeah, add some vertical jump in there as well and see if that solves your issue.